# Find uniques and show corresponding values as comma separated values in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table with large data containing family name and family households. And I am trying to get them in a unique list followed by the household names as comma separated values.

The table below explains the inputs and desired output.

[image: Unique Values and Corresponding Columns]

Here is the raw data.

| Household | Names |
| --- | --- |
| Smith | Jane |
| Boyer | Anya |
| Miller | Kate |
| Smith | John |
| Boyer | Doug |
| Boyer | Sam |
| Miller | Joe |
| Smith | Jim |
| Boyer | Jeff |

I did find a [similar request but it was for Python](https://superuser.com/questions/1453618/excel-find-unique-values-in-one-column-and-corresponding-values-from-another). I am looking for something in Excel that can do this. I tried Pivot table but it does not work, since it tries to agregate it.

Comment: While this *might* be doable in a spreadsheet, it would be **far** simpler in a database, with simple select statements. Office used to include Access, and the free LibreOffice *does* include the database *Base*. https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/lo/text/shared/guide/data_enter_sql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to accomplish the desired output, here are few ways that I have known till now:

▶️ Using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Household", type text}, {"Names", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Household"}, {{"Names", each Text.Combine([Names],", "), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

▶️ Using `GROUPBY()` function available in `MS365` **Office Insiders Version**:

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(A2:A10,B2:B10,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0)
```

---

▶️ Or, Using `LAMBDA()` helper function `BYROW()` --> Applicable to current channel `MS365`

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:B10,
     _household, TAKE(_data,,1),
     _names, UNIQUE(_household),
     HSTACK(_names, BYROW(_names, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(x=_household,TAKE(_data,,-1),""))))))
```

---

▶️ Or, Using `POWER PIVOT`, available in `Windows Excel 2013+` and `Excel 365 (Windows)`

[image]

---

To use Power Pivot follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_1`

---

- Select some cell in your data and click on `Insert` Tab -> Click on `Pivot Table` --> The `Table/Range` will shows as `Table_1`, Click on `New Worksheet` or `Existing Worksheet` as per your choice, --> If latter select the cell location and click on `Add this data the Data Model`.

---

- On right `Pivot Table` Fields Pane appears, right click on `Table_1` in the pane and select `Add Measure`

---

- Enter Measure Name as per your choice and enter the below formula in  the formula section:

---

```
=CONCATENATEX(Table_1,[Names],", ")
```

---

- Press Ok, Select `Household` and place in `ROWS` Area while the Measure Named as `Name-CommaSeparated` (used in this example, you may change it) in `VALUES` Area.

---

- From `Design` Tab change the `Report Layout` to `Show in Tabular Form`, next Click `Grand Totals` and select `Off for Rows and Columns` and you get the desired output.

---

⏩ Another alternative version for `Excel 2016+` onwards:

[image]

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(IF(D2=A$2:A$10,","&B$2:B$10,"")),",",,1)
```

---

The above formula needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode for older versions only.

---

Comment: Thank you. But when I try GROUPBY function, =GROUPBY(A2:A10,B2:B10,ARRAYTOTEXT,,0), it gives me an error #NAME?

Comment: @DigitalNomad all I have mentioned in the post. `GROUPBY()` applicable to `MS365` alternative solutions posted as well! If you are using `Excel 2010+` then you will need `Power Query` here

Comment: I have Office 365 and the GROUPBY function as you suggested does not work. Please validate that.

Comment: I have even mentioned that `GROUPBY()` is available in `MS365` Office Insiders Version. Kindly read my post. Everything I have mentioned.

Comment: You should rearrange your answer to Power Query first (Since most people are going to assume if they have O365, that GroupBy would work. Or at least, please make it more emphatic. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DigitalNomad alright will do it

Comment: Thank you. BTW the SUBSTITUTE solution that you proposed works the best (and easiest). Thanks. Marked as Answer.

Comment: That pretty much sums it all up @MayukhBhattacharya. Do I see a DAX measure in there ;)

Comment: @JvdV Sir, yes its there