# How to use transpose unique filter function to make a comma separated list in a single cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I need help using transpose(unique(filter) to essentially filter only be unique ID's and then convert the record number column into a list. I did this before and I showed the final result, but I forgot how to and I can't replicate it. Is it possible for someone to figure out the way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrPrr.png)

Comment: The final result looks same there is no difference. Also it seems you are using `Google Sheets` could clarify what you have tried so far. This should work: `=BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A12),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(B2:B12,A2:A12=x))))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find uniques and show corresponding values as comma separated values in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1833070/find-uniques-and-show-corresponding-values-as-comma-separated-values-in-excel)

Comment: Hello Mayukh (I'm looking to use tranpose unique filter to create the final result, I manually typed the final result in for example of what I'm looking for transpose to make vertical to horizontal, then set employee ID = to each other so only the employee ID 1,2,3 is individually pulled uniquely and filtered. =Transpose(unique(filter A2=A3, etc etc...) Also, I am doing this in excel I just sent the photo from sheets for example.

Comment: `Column D` has repeated values of `Column B` for only emp id 1 and rest as are missing. Sorry dont make sense to me

Comment: Yes, so I'm trying to transpose unique values per ID in column A in into column D. So I wanted to use a formula that will give me unique values in column B, but per ID. So ID 1 will repeat all the records for Column B for the same ID.

Comment: Please edit your post with what you have tried and the expected output.

Comment: Oh hold on I only typed the manual final result for the first 4. I didn't try any formula I'm trying to figure out how to use Transpose(unique(Filter X,X,X) to create my final result in column D. I forgot how to do that?

Comment: =Transpose(Unique(filter(B:B,A2=A3,"")

Answer (score 0):

According to your example a formula in `D2` to copy down:

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12=A2)))
```

Or a single-cell formula for the entire column:

```
=MAP($A$2:$A$12,LAMBDA(a,ARRAYTOTEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12=a)))))
```